# Craft 3 Launguage Switcher by certain group

Tags: craft3, language

I'm working on the language switcher and have it working. The only thing is I want it to pull from `group` `data-id=1` It's pulling from all sites because of the `i18n` to change the language name to it's native name.

I made a "disabled" group in Craft CMS 3 and put Russian in it and it shows up with `i18n`.  I had it working before by only the 2 letter abbreviation showed such as "de" instead of Deutsch and Russian didn't show.

```
<div class="language-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" id="language-menu">
{% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}
{% for siteInGroup in currentSite.getGroup.getSites() %}
   {% if siteInGroup.id == entry.siteId %}
      {% for locale in craft.i18n.getSiteLocales() %}
        <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ locale.getDisplayName() }}</a>
   {% else %}
      {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(siteInGroup).one() %}
        <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ locale.getDisplayName(siteInGroup.language) }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I figured it out:

```
    {% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}
{% for siteInGroup in currentSite.getGroup.getSites() %}
   {% if siteInGroup.id == entry.siteId %}
        <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ locale.getDisplayName() }}</a>
   {% else %}
      {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(siteInGroup).one() %}
      {% set locale = craft.i18n.getLocaleById(siteInGroup.language) %}
        <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ locale.getDisplayName(siteInGroup.language) }}</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following... what's the issue you're having and what's the behavior you're looking for?  What is `group` and `data-id=1`?

Comment: I have two site groups (disabled and live) and just want to show the live group on the language menu.

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind adding your solution as an official answer?